# How to get last synchronization date and server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I have a central suscriber with 5 publishers.  After replication, I want to get the last synchronization date and the server that made that synchronization.  Is it possible to find this information from existing tables that SQL Server uses for replication?

Answer (score 0):

I use something simmiler to this to check last replication times.  However this is on a database level and not a table level.  this is ran from the distribution database of the publisher.

```
SELECT      MAX(DISTINCT h.[time]) AS RunTime
FROM            MSmerge_history h INNER JOIN
        MSmerge_agents a ON a.id = h.agent_id
WHERE       (a.publisher_db = 'PublishedDbName') 
AND (h.runstatus <> 1) 
AND Left(h.comments,2) = 'Up' 
OR (a.publisher_db = 'PublishedDbName') 
AND (h.runstatus <> 1) 
AND Left(h.comments,2) = 'No' 
OR (a.publisher_db = 'PublishedDbName') 
AND (h.runstatus <> 1) 
AND Left(h.comments,2) = 'Me'
And Publication Like 'PublictionName%'
GO
```